# Failed to fetch curl when trying to install, 404 Not Found

Tags: command-line, curl

Attempting to revert a Chromebox with Windows 10 on it back to ChromeOS, using Ubuntu on a live boot to run a custom script to update the firmware. Basically, in order to run this command:

cd ~; curl -L -O http://mrchromebox.tech/firmware-util.sh; sudo bash firmware-util.sh

I have to have curl installed, so I try to install curl from the terminal, but this is the error message I get back:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
 libcurl4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 curl libcurl4
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 373 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1036 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 libcurl4 amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 libcurl4 amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.24 80]
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 curl amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 curl amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.24 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

What could be causing this issue and what can I do to fix it so that I can run the first command?

I'm very new to linux, Ubuntu, and this site as a whole, so if I've formatted anything wrong or my understanding of something is obviously wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Do you have internet connection? The packages you want to install have to be downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Running the following command did the trick for me:

```
sudo apt-get update
```